# Cannot find module 'async' in server

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I am deploying my nodejs project in linux server . I face the following error while try to run my nodejs .

```
Cannot find module 'async' in server.
```

I cant find out the reason. can anyone suggest me what i have to do.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "works",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.2.1",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.1",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.13.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.10.3",
    "mongoose": "^4.0.6",
    "morgan": "^1.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.7.0",
    "request": "^2.58.0"
  }
}
```

while installing `npm install`. I get following error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt-nodejs/0.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bcryptjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jwt-simple
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/moment
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/morgan
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonwebtoken
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: colors
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-    client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry- client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm- registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback ( /usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:156:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1256:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/siva/www/emoheal.com/emoheal/npm-  debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-17-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/siva/www/emoheal.com/emoheal
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: colors
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/siva/www/emoheal.com/emoheal/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

> My debug.log error

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', 'async' ]
info using npm@1.1.4
info using node@v0.6.19
verbose config file /home/siva/.npmrc
verbose config file /usr/etc/npmrc
verbose config file /usr/share/npm/npmrc
verbose caching /home/siva/www/emoheal.com/emoheal/package.json
verbose loadDefaults emoheal@0.0.0
verbose from cache /home/siva/www/emoheal.com/emoheal/package.json
verbose readDependencies: using package.json deps
verbose cache add [ 'async@^1.2.1', null ]
silly cache add: name, spec, args [ undefined, 'async@^1.2.1', [    'async@^1.2.1', null ] ]
verbose parsed url { pathname: 'async@^1.2.1',verbose parsed url   path: 'async@^1.2.1',verbose parsed url   href: 'async@^1.2.1' }
silly cache add: name, spec, args [ 'async', '^1.2.1', [ 'async',    '^1.2.1' ] ]
verbose parsed url { pathname: '^1.2.1', path: '^1.2.1', href: '^1.2.1'  }
verbose addNamed [ 'async', '^1.2.1' ]
verbose addNamed [ null, null ]
info addNameTag [ 'async', '^1.2.1' ]
verbose raw, before any munging async
verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './async' ]
verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/async
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: async
ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry- client/request.js:31:9)
ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:156:14)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1256:7)
ERR! You may report this log at:
ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
ERR! or use
ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/siva/www/emoheal.com/emoheal/npm- debug.log npm
ERR! 
ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-17-generic
ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "async"
ERR! node -v v0.6.19
ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: async
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: did you add it to package.json? can you paste your package.json here?

Comment: My package.json is {
  "name": "works",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.2.1",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.1",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.13.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.10.3",
    "mongoose": "^4.0.6",
    "morgan": "^1.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.7.0",
    "request": "^2.58.0"
  }
}

Comment: Node.js v0.6.19 was released 4 years ago! First try to update to newer version.

Comment: After changed version it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

guess you are talking about this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

you must install it first,
npm install async
than it will be in your node_modules folder and you can require it.

Comment: while installing "npm install async " . it too throws error

Comment: which is? come on, you must provide more details.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'async'
   at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
   at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
   at require (module.js:375:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/siva/www/emoheal.com/emoheal/server.js:3:13)
   at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
   at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:353:32)
   at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
   at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)

Comment: you said WHILE installing it throws an error. anyway... go to where your code is, check you have a node_modules folder in parallel and that in it you have async folder. if you don't, you are either running your node.js wrong, or installed it wrong. you give out too few details to help you. here are few links you must read: https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/modules.html and https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally

Comment: is node_modules folder created dynamically ?  or else we need to create that folder ..

Comment: its created for you dynamically

Comment: what error? do I have to guess what error? is there a reason you are not providing any info?

Comment: so... lets start... now I see your npm fails. you ignored that, and tried to run the app although npm install fails. great. next... you do not provide the npm debug log so we can see the issue why npm fails which is the issue you have basicallly, not that you can't load async.

Comment: Sagie. I update my question with my debug.log. kindly go throw that .and give suggestion

Comment: not sure it is the issue but npm 1 and node 0.6? those are ancient. use npm 3 and node 4 or node 6. i'm not sure those old platforms are still supported.

Comment: Excellent and by the way many modules dont support node 0.6 so it was important regardless.

Answer (score -1):

Enter to project folder and run:

```
npm install
```

This command install all project dependencies from `package.json`

Comment: see my updated question above . while installing npm install.  i got that error